# UITableView on iPad is always gray colour with no separators

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a table view (not `UITableViewController`) in a `UIViewController`, which is my second controller in the "Navigation Controller". The table shows fine but when I change the style to Grouped it shows plain gray colour  with no separators at all, even the controller not responding to methods in the assigned controller. I have ensured the table view has been linked to the `delegate` and the `dataSource`. The same procedure works for the iPhone.

[image]

Comment: Please make sure you have implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method from its `delegate`

Comment: This might be an obvious question, but have actually added any cells to the table yet?

Comment: @ShaanSingh thanks man, it was that number of cells, the "array" doesn't return anything, but I don't understand is, how it works fine for iPhone

Comment: @AyanSengupta thanks for ur comment, the issue was the number of cells, where the "Array wasn't returning anything. "shaanSingh" figure it out.

Comment: For someone beneficial, the data wasn't showing up in the second view controller when i select a cell in the first one, the problem was, I suppose to pass the selected cell to the second controller using "segue" function, but I forgot to give "segue" an identifier.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment:

In order to show grouped cells, the array has to return data for the cells to use.